# how to find the a particular value from the available python dictionary and print the name of the dictionary in which that value is present

Tags: python-2.7

I am beginner in python.I have a particular value let say 30 and i have 5 python dictionary having keys and values.i want a function which iterates through every dictionary and checks whether that value is present or not, and if that value present then print name of that dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would do it would be to add all your dictionaries to a master dictionary, like below, - (Ive only used 3 for a minimal example):

```
master = {'one':{'a':10, 'b':20, 'c':30}, 'two':{'d':40, 'e':50, 'f':60}, 'three':{'g':70, 'h':80, 'i':90}}
```

The keys within your master are the 'names' of your dictionaries. This is what will be printed/returned when you find the value you are looking for.

Then I would use something like the simple function below:

```
def find_Value(master, value_to_find):
    for name, obj in master.iteritems():
        for sub_key, sub_value in obj.iteritems():
            if sub_value == value_to_find:
                return name
```

And then call the `find_Value()` function with the required `master` object and the desired integer `value_to_find`, like so.

```
print find_Value(master, 40)
```

Hope this helps!
Luke